# make only accessible for Admin in Website with Angual

Tags: angularjs, authentication, admin

I have a few components in my "shop-website". There is one component which should only be accessible for the Admin. In the local Storage there is a token isAdmin. I have now implemented that a special component is just shown in the home site when  the admin is logged in. But id you enter the link of this component(http://localhost:4200/Authorize) it shows everyone. How can I implement that it should be accessible only for Admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use canActivate in your routes definition.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ])
  ],
})
```

You can create custom conditions as AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
  ) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (somthing) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Check the documentation https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate